# Inserting a value into a sql database by using a sql query

Tags: c#, sql

This is my first row where I create a track (THIS WORKS)

```
String TrackAdd = "INSERT INTO Track (Titel) VALUES (@Titel)";

using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(TrackAdd, connection))
{

    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Titel", textBoxTitel.Text);
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Then I want to use the ID which was just created for this Track, I need it so I can link it to something else (in this case a genre. I have specified the names for genres in a different table and need their IDs) 
I'm now trying this but its not working and I don't really know what to do.

```
using (var connection = Database.connection)
{
    String Track1Genre = "INSERT INTO TrackGenre (TrackId, GenreId) VALUES (@TrackId, @GenreId)";
    string Genre = listBoxGenre.GetItemText(listBoxGenre.SelectedItem);
    using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(Track1Genre, connection))
    {

        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TrackId", "Select Id from Track WHERE Titel = textBoxTitel.Text");
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GenreId", "Select Id from Genre where Genre = Genre");
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

NOTE: There's nothing wrong with the connection or anything, I just need help how to get the ID's out of the database and insert them into a different table

Comment: using inline query is not a good practice

Comment: Do your selects in separate sql queries (and separate sql commands)  before you execute that insert command and you'll be fine. You can't insert a query and assume it will somehow be executed and yield a result!

Comment: The values are probably already into the database.  ExecuteNonQuery returns an integer which indicates the number of rows effected by the query.  When you get a return value of zero it indicates that the data is already in the database and you need to use an Update to change the data.  A database is really a one flat spreadsheet like excel spreadsheet with tables  which are view of the database showing only certain columns.  When you insert data into one table it will automatically show up in all tables in the database.  So it may not be necessary to move data to another table.

Comment: I would create a stored procedure that sets the new id on an OUTPUT parameter. After the command is executed, the parameter will have the new id value. I know you probably don't know what I'm talking about but it should start you Googling.

Comment: Please try my below answer by using store procedure with temp variable to handle the identity value to insert next table.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to do it:

**Output Inserted.Id**

```
INSERT INTO Track (Titel) VALUES output INSERTED.ID (@Titel)
```

and in C#, use:

```
int lastId =(int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

**Identity_Insert On**

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Track ON; 
INSERT INTO Track (Id, Titel) VALUES (1, @Titel)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Track OFF;
```

In this method you already know what Id you are inserting so you can just use this to update your `TrackGenre` table. But, yes, you have to track your Ids or may be before executing check for last id using `select max(id) from Track`

Answer (score -1):

You're close. You can't *inject* SQL the way you intended. You have to move that your insert statement so the query will do a select for each value based on your parameters.

Let's try to workout what the SQL query that gets executed will look like, when you start with this:

```
String Track1Genre = "INSERT INTO TrackGenre (TrackId, GenreId) VALUES (@TrackId, @GenreId)";
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TrackId", "Select Id from Track WHERE Titel = textBoxTitel.Text");
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GenreId", "Select Id from Genre where Genre = Genre");
```

Remember that whatever (string) value is set on a parameter will be used, without any evaluation. So the above statement will lead to this sql being executed:

```sql
INSERT INTO TrackGenre (TrackId, GenreId) 
VALUES ('Select Id from Track WHERE Titel = textBoxTitel.Text', 
        'Select Id from Genre where Genre = Genre');
```

So it nicely did prevent a [SqlInjection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) but it didn't return Id's to tables Track and Genre either, in fact it would bark about a conversion failed to data type int.

Instead you can pass the selection parameters as is and then use those in the queries to get the id's of the rows you're interested in.

Staying as close as possible to what you currently have, this would work:

```
using (var connection = Database.connection)
{
    String Track1Genre = @"
      INSERT 
      INTO TrackGenre(TrackId, GenreId) 
      VALUES (
        (SELECT id FROM track WHERE titel = @titel), /* do a select for the ID */
        (SELECT id FROM genre WHERE genre = @genre))";

    string Genre = listBoxGenre.GetItemText(listBoxGenre.SelectedItem);
    using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(Track1Genre, connection))
    {

        // caution, better use Add, see the note
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@titel", textBoxTitel.Text);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Genre", Genre);
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the insert statement will fail if you have tracks with the same title, or genre's with same name. But that is up to you to handle or prevent from happening upstream.

If you want to be 100% sure that the Id you get from the insert of Track, refer to the *Output Inserted.Id* option in the answer of [Sunil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47926299/578411). You'll have to bring the `lastid` variable over to the code I've shown here, replacing the first parameter with it (and adapt the insert query accordingly).

**Note**
There is a potential issue with the use of `AddWithValue` as explained in this blogpost from JCoohorn: https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

It is better to prevent the SqlParameter class guess your type wrong. Consider to use

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@titel", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250).Value = textBoxTitel.Text;
```

instead.

If you want to experiment with the insert query first to get the feel what it is doing, fork [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/773729).

Answer (score -2):

I dont know if it is a typo or genuine mistake which should be corrected

this line from your code

```
 sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TrackId", "Select Id from Track WHERE Titel = textBoxTitel.Text");
```

should be written like this

```
 sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TrackId", "Select Id from Track WHERE Titel = " + textBoxTitel.Text);
```

same problem is with Genre tooo. if your code written is correct then your query is actually searching for 'textBoxTitel.Text' instead of trackid